# SimpleJSON in Unity not parsing

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to parse a .json file in Unity using [SimpleJSON](https://github.com/Bunny83/SimpleJSON), but the parsing is returning null.

My parser class:

```
[SerializeField]
private string phrasesFileJSON = "conversations.json";

private JSONNode data;

public void Init () {
    string jsonFile = phrasesFileJSON.Replace (".json", "");

    TextAsset jsonObj = Resources.Load<TextAsset> (jsonFile);        
    data = JSONNode.Parse (jsonObj.ToString ());

    Debug.Log ("Data null? " + !data);
    Debug.Log (jsonObj.ToString());
}
```

The Debugs print:

```
Data null? True
```

and

```
{
  "0-0": {
    "speech": "Hello! This is a test phrase.",
    "keyword": "Mountain"
  }
}
```

So the file is read correctly, but JSONNode is failing to parse it. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is read appropriately, and `JSONNode` parses it properly.

However, in your `Debug.Log` you are implicitly casting `data` to a `bool`, which the library you are using has overridden the default behavior.

If you want to check if the JSONNode contains data, you should use `.Count`

[image]